# Diferencia entre $http.get() y $http.post() ... ¿Cuál es mejor y en qué caso usar cuál?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, get, http-get

Estoy intentando acceder de la manera más corta y rápida posible a un archivo de mi  servidor para **Descargar un archivo** con jQuery, y ya lo he hecho antes con AJAX y `$.post("http://evaluaciondocente.ml/data/_.php");`, pero me encuentro con que también es empleado el método `$http.post()` y `$http.get()`, acompañados con el prefijo `$http`.
De hecho, entre unas de las funciones `$http.post()`, que he visto, lleva también una cabecera: `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}`
¿Qué fin tiene ésta cabecera dentro del método `$http.post()` ?

Comment: Hola espero poder ayudarte   {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' es el tipo de petición que hacer, la diferencia entre get y post es que post es mas seguro porque no mandas información a través de la url a diferencia del get  $.get("http://evaluaciondocente.ml/data/id_usuario_ejemplo"), si quieres solo acceder a un archivo usa get es más rápido

Comment: Mil gracias @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim , gracias por colaborarme.
Quisiera saber, además de acceder al archivo que está en dicha url por método $.get(), ¿sabes depronto cómo puedo hacer para descargarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esa pregunta estas liando dos cosas que te voy a desmembrar para que lo entiendas mas, una petición HTTP tiene varias caracteristicas:

- Tipo, que pueden ser (GET,POST,UPDATE,DELETE....)
- Cabecera o Headers, que lleva la información de configuración la petición.
- Cuerpo o Body, que almacenan la información de la petición

Las peticiones HTTP se pueden realizar en cualquier combinación ya que el protocolo no es restrictivo con esto, pero lo habitual es utilizar las peticiones **GET** para solicitar datos comunes sin esperar un procesamiento previo y para las peticiones que realizan un procesamiento se suelen utilizar el metodo **POST**.

Para la transmisión de información hay que saber que todo lo que envies en la petición debe tener un tipo MIME en la cabecera que describa lo que envias, que es un MIME, pues si entrar mucho en detalle es esto:

> **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

esto lo que describe es que el contenido de tu petición vendrá almacenado en la URL de la dirección.

Lo norma dicta (recuerda que el protocolo no es restrictivo y puedes hacer lo que quieras) que las peticiones **GET** llevan sus parametros en las URL y por consiguiente van a llevar un **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** y para las peticiones **POST** llevan los datos en el body y suelen ir en protocolo JSON llevando una header con este valor **application/json**.

Con esto sabes lo minimo de como interactuamos usando HTTP. La clave y tu duda es la siguiente, el servidor HTTP recibe la petición analiza la cabeceras y en función de la información de las cabecera realiza lo que necesita, por ejemplo la extracción de datos. Por eso indicamos como viene almacenado la información en las cabeceras, espero que te ayude.

Answer (score 1):

Hola yo tengo hago esto en un proyecto para poder descargar, cada que hace una petición por navegador desde el buscador estás haciendo un **GET** así que si ya tienes un get que te devuelva un archivo con esto lo deberías de poder ver.

```js
$('#pdf').click(() => {
  window.open("/tu/url");
});
```

```html
<a id="pdf" href="" class="pull-right">
  <font size="12"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i></font>
</a>
```